# How do i get meeting duration in react-native-zoom-us

Tags: react-native, zoom-sdk

```
import ZoomUs, { ZoomEmitter } from 'react-native-zoom-us';

const testData=await ZoomUs.initialize({
   clientKey: 'Your client key',
   clientSecret: 'your client secret',
   domain: 'zoom.us',
 });

 const joinMeetingResult =
      await ZoomUs.joinMeeting({
       autoConnectAudio: true,
       userName: 'Wick',
       meetingNumber: "87606544441" ,
       password: "123456",
     });
```

Every thing is perfectly working I need the duration when user leave meeting after joining the meeting

Comment: Maybe set a timestamp when the user joins then listen for an end meeting event, when you get the desired event set another timestamp then calc time difference: https://github.com/mieszko4/react-native-zoom-us/blob/master/docs/EVENTS.md

Comment: Sir i had tried it but event is not called when i leave the meeting.